# How does ReVTeX's bibliography control work?

Tags: bibtex, revtex

In the ReVTeX bst file, which I am adapting for my own text, there is this portion of code:

```
FUNCTION {control.decode}
{
  - duplicate$
  #0 <
    {
      skip$ pop$ swap$ #0
    }
    {
      swap$ pop$ swap$ #1
    }
  if$
  swap$ :=
}
FUNCTION {control.author.decode}
{
  control.author
  duplicate$ duplicate$ #0 < swap$ #128 < not or
    {
      int.to.str$ "(" swap$ * ")" *
      "Control cannot interpret author " swap$ *
      warning$
    }{
      'control.author.jnrlst   swap$ duplicate$ #64 control.decode
      'control.author.dotless  swap$ duplicate$ #32 control.decode
      'control.author.nospace  swap$ duplicate$ #16 control.decode
      'control.author.initials swap$ duplicate$  #8 control.decode
      'control.author.nocomma  swap$ duplicate$  #4 control.decode
      'control.author.first    swap$ duplicate$  #2 control.decode
      'control.author.reversed swap$ duplicate$  #1 control.decode
      duplicate$ #0 =
        'skip$
        {
          "Control: residue of author"
          "(" swap$ * ")" * *
          warning$
        }
      if$
      pop$
    }
  if$
}
```

This code sets the author display options which I want to mess with. The options are set as follows:

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="42",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}
```

Where the `42` represents some option setting (I think, because choosing random values like 3, 7 and 00) produces warnings related to these options. Can anyone explain to me how these are 'decoded'? I'd like to figure out what these actually do to the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea here is that `control.author` can pass information about a variety of options all encoded into one number. This is the standard idea of using different bits of a number to pass a series of boolean settings. To 'recover' the data, `control.author.decode` first does a test that `control.author` is in range (greater than 0, less than 128). That's done by

```
control.author
duplicate$ duplicate$ #0 < swap$ #128 < not or
```

which leaves on the input stack the value of `control.author` and the logical result (a `1` or a `0`): the postfix language picks up the latter as part of the `if$`. Assuming the test passes, the block

```
'control.author.jnrlst   swap$ duplicate$ #64 control.decode
'control.author.dotless  swap$ duplicate$ #32 control.decode
'control.author.nospace  swap$ duplicate$ #16 control.decode
'control.author.initials swap$ duplicate$  #8 control.decode
'control.author.nocomma  swap$ duplicate$  #4 control.decode
'control.author.first    swap$ duplicate$  #2 control.decode
'control.author.reversed swap$ duplicate$  #1 control.decode
```

the puts the *name* of each setting on to the stack followed by the value needed to extract it bitwise and then a call to the common decoder. For example

```
'control.author.jnrlst   swap$ duplicate$ #64 control.decode
```

with the input `42` will have on the stack

```
"control.author.jnrlst" #42 #42 #64
```

just before calling `control.decode`. The later takes the end value (`64` here: the 'test value') away from the current value for the controls (here `42`). If the input was larger than the 'test' value then the flag (here `control.author.jnrlst`) would be set to `1` (true) and the resulting residue would be left in the input for the next test. As the test fails, the input value (`42`) is retained and the flag is set to `0` (false). Working that through will set each flag to true/false and should use up all of the input (*i.e.* for any number which is in range the result of the tests should be a value of 0).

In the example given, a value for the `authors` setting of `42` breaks down into 32 + 8 + 2, *i.e.* setting `control.author.dotless`, `control.author.initials` and `control.author.first` true and the other settings false. Thus to work out the 'correct' value, decide which settings you want active, look at the code to find the appropriate value and add them all together.

Comment: Wow!, great explanation... In addition it made me remember how the permissions are set in Unix-like OS! XD